# Excel 2016 Connecting to oData Feed Received (406) Not Acceptable Response

Tags: excel, odata

I'm working with Power Query in Excel 2016 and when trying to setup an oData Feed (Data Tab > New Query > From Other Sources > From OData Feed) I get a message back saying (406) Not Acceptable.  Normally on the OData Feed, I put in the URL (Basic is selected by default) and it opens up an authentication window (to put in username and password).

I have two excel workbooks now with one being created about four weeks ago, using the same process and it works as expected; one can even select refresh data and it makes the connection and refreshes the data.

The second excel workbook is a new, created from scratch (as I wanted to go through a bit of a different path with the Power Query editor), but I cannot get past the OData feed creation.

It seems odd that the same URL that was setup before is not working in a new spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was purely an issue with selecting oData as the feed.  I'm connecting to JIRA rest web services and should have selected (Data Tab > New Query > From Other Sources > From Web) (the From Web over From OData Feed made all the difference)